# Path Connectedness of Simply Connected Space Minus a Point

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, path-connected

Suppose that $X$ is a simply connected topological manifold of dimension at-least $2$.  Fix a point $x \in X$ and define $\tilde{X}\triangleq X-\{x\}$.  How can I prove that the $0^{th}$ signular homology group of $\tilde{X}$ is trivial?

I'm trying to use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I restricted to the case (which I initially cared about) which is a topological manifold of dimension at-least $2$.

Comment: Connected topological manifolds of dimension $\geq 2$ don't have cut points. That's because $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not have cut points for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Ya this seems intuitively clear to me...I guess I should remove a sufficiently small open neiberhood and justify this by MV long-exact sequence?  Then reduce the argument to Euclidean space.

Comment: Here's a sketch: pick $a,b\in \tilde{X}$. Connect them via $\lambda$ in $X$. All we have to do is ensure that $\lambda$ doesn't cross $x$. So consider an Euclidean closed ball $D$ around $x$ such that $a,b\not\in D$. Now you pick first intersection $t_1$ of $\lambda$ with $\partial D$ and the last intersection $t_2$. Now you modify $\lambda$: it goes normally from $a$ to $t_1$. It goes from $t_1$ to $t_2$ around $\partial D$ (which is possible due to dimension $\geq 2$) and finally from $t_2$ to $b$ as $\lambda$. Newly created path doesn't cross $x$ obviously.

Comment: This seems reasonable.  Do you know of a book which deals with cut-points, I've only come across them in lecture notes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freakish argument in the comments is more elementary, but I thought you might appreciate an argument using a Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Let $n=\dim X$,  let $\varphi:U\to\mathbb R^n$ be a chart at $x$ with $\varphi(x)=0$, and let $V=X\setminus\varphi^{-1}(\overline B(0,1))$.  Then $U\approx\mathbb R^n$, $V\approx\tilde X$, $U\cap V\approx S^{n-1}$.  Since $\pi_1X=0$, the Hurewicz theorem implies $H_1(X)=0$, so the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the decomposition $X=U\cup V$ gives us a short exact sequence
$$0\to H_0(U\cap V)\to H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V)\to H_0(X)\to 0.$$
With the above identifications, this gives us 
$$0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\oplus H_0(\tilde X)\to\mathbb Z\to 0,$$
forcing $H_0(\tilde X)$ to be $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So $\tilde{X}\triangleq X-\{x\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, as you defined it.

Comment: Ooops right :)  Thanks again, super helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!